# Ada Compilation problem

Tags: gcc, ada

hello I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am using Code::blocks for writing c program as well as Ada program. C is compiling and running fine when I am using the command "gcc -o test test.c" but when I am compiling my Ada program there is the following error

```
$ gcc -c hello.adb 
gcc: error trying to exec 'gnat1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I have installed GNAT from ubuntu software center.  Please tell me how to ignore this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem. I installed GNAT and GPS on Mac OS from Adacore. I found a directory containing a bunch of Ada related binaries including gcc

```
/opt/gps/bin
```

But using either this version of gcc or the default installed on my machine I get the following error

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'gnat1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I had to use the gcc binary located in

```
/Users/dale/opt/GNAT/2018/bin/
```

And it works. So I think as someone else commented this may be due to the version of gcc you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
$ gnatmake hello.adb
```

Comment: Cant't work without installing `gnat` and OPs question says, that the package isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, install the GNU-Ada-Compiler via the command below

```
sudo apt-get install gnat
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem with compiling ada.

I think the problem is that your computer is using your old gcc, instead of the ada-aware gcc included in gnat.

If you install gnat from adacore, you will get a binary folder which you add to path.
I don't know about what the ubuntu GNAT package does, but you'll have the binaries somewhere in your system.

You can reorder your PATH to place the GNAT gcc earlier. Or you can explicitly call the location of the gnat gcc.